# Clear Internet Explorer's address bar using C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, ieaddon

I am developing an IE add-on in C# and I need to clear the IE's address bar, i.e. set it to empty string but stay on the current page. This page is an html located on the localhost and replaces the default Start Page of IE.
When a user opens a new tab, the address bar should be empty and not contain the ugly path to the html file.

To put it in a nutshell: Is it possible to programmatically clear the address bar but still stay on the loaded page. If so, how?

Comment: I don't think so but maybe a custom protocol handler can help you out so you can have something like: `app:start` much like `about:blank`.

Comment: it this for something illegal? :D

Comment: Thanks rene, any suggestions for a handler? And no, it is not illegal...This is a standard feature in chrome/firefox extensions.